# Scrapy crawl web with many duplicated element class name

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm new to the Scrapy and trying to crawl the web but the HTML element consist of many DIV that have duplicated class name  eg.

```
<section class= "pi-item pi-smart-group pi-border-color">

<section class="pi-smart-group-head">
    <h3 class = "pi-smart-data-label pi-data-label pi-secondary-font pi-item-spacing">
</section>

    <section class= "pi-smart-group-body">
        <div class="pi-smart-data-value pi-data-value pi-font pi-item-spacing">
            <a href="abc" title="!! What I want !!"> </a>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

My problem is that this structure repeat for many other element and when I'm using `response.css` I will get multiple element which I didn't want

(Basically I want to crawl the Pokemon information eg. "Types", "Species" and "Ability" of each Pokemon from https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Bulbasaur , I have done get url for all Pokemon but stuck in getting information from each Pokemon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to do this scrapy project for you and got the results. The issue I see is that you have used CSS. You can scrape with that, but it is far more effective to use Xpath selectors. You have more versatility to select the specific tags you want. Here is the code I wrote for you. Bare in mind, this code is just something I did quickly to get your results. It works but I did it in this way so it is easy for you understand it since you are new to scrapy. Please let me know if this is helpful

```
import scrapy


class PokemonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pokemon_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Bulbasaur']

    def parse(self, response):
        pokemon_type = response.xpath("(//div[@class='pi-data-value pi-font'])[1]/a/@title")
        pokemon_species = response.xpath('//div[@data-source="species"]//div/text()')
        pokemon_abilities = response.xpath('//div[@data-source="ability"]/div/a/text()')

        yield {
            'pokemon type': pokemon_type.extract(),
            'pokemon species': pokemon_species.extract(),
            'pokemon abilities': pokemon_abilities.extract()
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath expression with a property text:

```
abilities = response.xpath('//h3[a[.="Abilities"]]/following-sibling::div[1]/a/text()').getall()
species = response.xpath('//h3[a[.="Species"]]/following-sibling::div[1]/text()').get()
```